# Compile error after upgrade Gradle version to 3.0.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

Here is the error log.

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.java'

Comment: more details and code pls

Comment: @NirajSanghani what code you need to look into?

Comment: kotlin or java?

Comment: it's built with java

Comment: ok check my answer

Comment: what android studio version are u using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your databindings are creating some issues

Use as below if you are using the newer version

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1'
```

or for older

```
 compile 'com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1'
```

Also, make sure you added the new repo in root gradle.build

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

You may also use with newer Gradle wrapper:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            google()
        }
    }
```

If you have used data binding in repo, then make sure you have added:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 version as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used databinding :(

Comment: in any case make sure u did put in all changes i mentioned if ur using 3.0

Comment: which one is for data binding fix?

Comment: dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    } this line did a magic :)