# Error:Manifest Tasks does not support the manifestOutputFile property any more, please use the manifestOutputDirectory instead. (Android Studio 3.0)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I get below error when I had migrated to Android Studio 3.0 recently.

**Error:Manifest Tasks does not support the manifestOutputFile property any more, please use the manifestOutputDirectory instead.**

I tried following the steps in:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html but still get the same error.

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Module's build.gradle is as follows:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.rakesh"

            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }

        dataBinding {
            enabled true
        }

    }


    buildscript {

        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: please add the `build.gradle`, else it is not possible to provide an answer.

Comment: the module's build gradle would be rather interesting, because obviously nothing happens in the top-most project `build.gradle`, concerning any `manifestOutputFile`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have added the module's build.gradle too. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this issue? None of the suggestions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the new repo in root `gradle.build`:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

You may also use with newer Gradle wrapper:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            google()
        }
    }
```

If you have used data binding in repo, then make sure you have added:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 version as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a copy and paste [of the most part of your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949494/472495). Please note that we discourage deliberate answer duplication here, as it raises the maintenance overhead of keeping things up to date (and identical answers tend to diverge). Therefore, if you see two questions that can be answered identically, please vote to close one of them, or point the OP to the other question. Or, if they are different, please tailor your answers to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, please refrain from using txtspk here. Words like "you" and "your" are not hard to type, but for some English speakers, their chat abbreviations are irritating and awkward to read. We prefer a technical standard of writing here, as much as possible - this is not Reddit!

Answer (score 0):

once having seen the actual `build.gradle` ...

you need to build with `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` (or later), which is the least required version - while there are no instructions, which would be directly related to the given error message. it's a little strange, that it does not complain about the `buildToolsVersion` mismatch, in the first place.

the `buildscript` part does not belong into there (removing that from the module's `build.gradle` might already be the remedy). also, delete the `.gradle` and all the `build` directories, before trying to build.