# After upgrading to Android studio 3 (stable version) I get this error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle sync failed: 
Manifest Tasks does not support the **manifestOutputFile** property any more, please use the **manifestOutputDirectory** instead.
                For more information, please check

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html
I opened the link and applied it but still can not solve my problem ..
it was said to add this code in build.gradle module app ..

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.processManifest.doLast {
                // Stores the path to the maifest.
                String manifestPath = "$manifestOutputDirectory/AndroidManifest.xml"
                // Stores the contents of the manifest.
                def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText()
                // Changes the version code in the stored text.
                manifestContent = manifestContent.replace('android:versionCode="1"',
                        String.format('android:versionCode="%s"', generatedCode))
                // Overwrites the manifest with the new text.
                file(manifestPath).write(manifestContent)
            }
        }

    }
```

I may apply it in wrong way because no resources that cover this topic.

I also try this answer .. [Error:Manifest Tasks does not support the manifestOutputFile property any more, please use the manifestOutputDirectory instead. (Android Studio 3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089953/errormanifest-tasks-does-not-support-the-manifestoutputfile-property-any-more)

for all my trials the error still exist ..

Comment: Clean your project and check. Your manifest/gradle file may contain some error. After 3.0 Android Studio merge both these files and show in Merged Manifest file.

Comment: I already do it but nothing changed .. @Prag'sシ